# Save as PDF from Word makes pixelated PDF in Acrobat but not Preview

Tags: ms-office, preview, font, pdf

I have a 2 year old MBP. I'm using Word 2008 and if I create a PDF using Save As... or  Print > PDF, the resulting PDF will look fantastic when viewed with Preview. However, if I open the same document in Acrobat it looks heavily pixelated.

Is there any explanation for why this is happening? Or how it can be fixed?
Thx!

See attached photos[image: the first is a screenshot from Preview]

[image: the second is a screenshot from Acrobat]

The first screenshot is from Preview and the second is from Acrobat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, OS X has built in font-rendering that Preview uses, which tends to look pretty great.

Adobe Acrobat must be using their own custom software to render fonts that isn't as good.  Unfortunately, it is up to Adobe to fix their font rendering.  You might want to look for an Acrobat setting that enables anti-aliasing which might help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the font is being rendered differently in each application. It's possible you have two copies of the same font family installed, and Acrobat is using a different one to render. I've had similar problems where Office installed duplicate versions of fonts that caused some rendering weirdness.

Try opening the **Font Book** application, and select **Look for Enabled Duplicates…** under the *Edit* menu. If you have any duplicates enabled, disable them, and then see if the rendering changes.

Comment: Thanks. I did the search you suggested, but there were no enabled duplicates found. Good idea, though.